# Rows of Rcpp::DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp, rcpp11

I have this code

```
 // [[Rcpp::export]]
void testDf(Rcpp::DataFrame pq)
{
  Rcpp::NumericVector p = pq[1];
  std::cout<<p[2]<<std::endl;
}
```

Which is the right way of accessing an element of **virtual** row of a particular column . But if I do this

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void testDf(Rcpp::DataFrame pq)
{
  std::cout<<pq[1][2]<<std::endl;
 }
```

It return to me an error that **operator[] is ambiguous** . 
But if we see, DataFrame is just a set of vectors. From the Data structure point of view DataFrame will hold **pointers** to set of vectors. So the **[]** operator will return me a pointer and I can further access the pointer's different element through dereferencing it. 
Please correct me if I am wrong. Just started with the awesome Rcpp package. I am having few theoretical questions like this. I will be grateful for the answers.

Comment: You should get the column first in a classed variable then the row of the column. http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/modifying-a-data-frame/ has an example (it's setting a value there but the idiom holds for getting).

Comment: No... No I know how to edit or subset a data frame. I want to know why that "[]" operator cannot be used successively ...